# Can anybody advise what type of connector this is?

Tags: pcb-design

I recently purchased an LiPower shield from SparkFun.

I also bought a Lithium Polymer battery off eBay and it appears to have a JST male connector (i could be wrong)?

I expected it to slot right into the board however the fit is slightly too large. Can any advise me of the name of the connector for the board battery supply, or have I mistaken the battery output connector?

Please see pictures below, thanks!

[image: Iso view]

[image: Battery connection lead]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The board uses a JST PH connector, with 2.0mm spacing. The battery has a JST XH connector, with 2.5mm spacing. You will need to replace the battery connector or put a XH socket on the board.

Answer (score 3):

That is generically a "JST" connector.  Named from the company that originally designed and made them.  But I believe there are many "second-source" (and likely counterfeit) sources of similar or identical connectors.

They are avaiable in a variety of mechanical configurations (horizontal, vertical, PC board mount, wire-end, etc. etc.)  And there are several variations with different pin sizes and pin-pitch (distance between the pins). They all look very similar, especially in photographs, but as you demonstrate, the different pitch families are NOT inter-connectable.

If you had bought the battery from SparkFun, it is quite likely that it would have the mating connector.  But since there is no standardization here, you will end up dealing with these kinds of mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

header on the board IS jst XHA connector,but wirinhg harness is XH,[image]